# Find voltage across load resistor

Tags: resistors, npn, zener

[image]

Here the zener voltage of the zener diode is 3.3V and base to emitter voltage drop is 0.7V. What is the voltage across the load resistor and how to find it?

Comment: This appears to be homework with no attempt at a solution. Please edit your question (using the 'edit' link underneath) to make an attempt at explaining how you think the circuit should work and then we can look at some numbers if you are on the right track.

Comment: I wonder if there is a real-life use for such a circuit…

Comment: Looks like a Darlington arranged to prevent the load voltage from exceeding some maximum voltage. Trivial to work out when that happens, though there will be a *soft* transition period before the clamped voltage across the load is rock solid. (Or, it could just be a shunt regulator of sorts.)